# How to select the last set of concatenated sequence from multiple similar sequence

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I have an int array, it's a concatenated array from multiple similar arrays all starting at 1.

1, 2, 3, 4
1, 2
1, 2, 3
1, 2

```
int[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 };
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the "last set" of the result which is {1, 2}.

**Attempt**:

```
int[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 };

List<int> lastSet = new List<int>();
var totalSets = list.Count(x => x == 1);

int encounter = 0;
foreach (var i in list)
{
    if (i == 1)
        encounter += 1;

    if (encounter == totalSets)
        lastSet.Add(i);
}

lastSet.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Is there a better way to achieve this using LINQ, perhaps `SkipWhile`, `GroupBy`, `Aggregate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can either make your list be an actual `List<int>` or if it doesn't bother you to create a copy of the list via `.ToList()`, you can do this:

```
var list = new[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 }.ToList();
var lastSet = list.Skip(list.LastIndexOf(1)).ToList();
```

Otherwise, `Aggregate` can work, but it's a little ugly:

```
var lastSet = list.Aggregate(new List<int>{1}, (seed, i) => {
    if(i == 1) {seed.Clear(); }
    seed.Add(i);
    return seed;
})
```

#### Update

As dtb points out, you can use Array.LastIndexOf rather than creating a List:

```
var list = new[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 };
var lastSet = list.Skip(Array.LastIndexOf(list, 1)).ToList();
```

Comment: @dtb: Hehe, yeah, of course. For some reason I didn't read the part saying that it would definitely be an `int[]`, so I just assumed he'd be using `IEnumerable<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

Works for any `IEnumerable` (but is slower than direct `List` versions)

```
var sub = list.Reverse<int>()
              .TakeWhile(i => i != 1)
              .Concat(new[]{1})
              .Reverse<int>();
```

Run a `ToArray()` on the result if you like.

Comment: Beat me to it.  My thoughts exactly.

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of `Enumerable.Repeat`, use `new[]{1}`. It's shorter, faster, and (I think) easier to read.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior thanks, you're right. I would really love a framework extension method that is like `Enumerable.Return(1)`, because it comes up so often. I forget arrays can be instantiated without type info.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [GroupAdjacent Extension Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10544835) below, you can split the list into the sequences beginning with 1 and then take the last sequence:

```
var result = list.GroupAdjacent((g, x) => x != 1)
                 .Last()
                 .ToList();
```

with

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacent<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> adjacent)
{
    var g = new List<T>();
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        if (g.Count != 0 && !adjacent(g, x))
        {
            yield return g;
            g = new List<T>();
        }
        g.Add(x);
    }
    yield return g;
}
```

Comment: Nice extension, always a common use case and so much more efficient than `GroupBy` which has to buffer to know it got it correct (this can  be - and is - lazy).

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is overrated:

```
int[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 };

int pos = Array.LastIndexOf(list, 1);

int[] result = new int[list.Length - pos];
Array.Copy(list, pos, result, 0, result.Length);

// result == { 1, 2 }
```

---

Now with 100% more readable:

```
int[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 };

int[] result = list.Slice(list.LastIndexOf(1));

// result == { 1, 2 }
```

where

```
static int LastIndexOf<T>(this T[] array, T value)
{
    return Array.LastIndexOf<T>(array, value);
}

static T[] Slice<T>(this T[] array, int offset)
{
    return Slice(array, offset, array.Length - offset);
}

static T[] Slice<T>(this T[] array, int offset, int length)
{
    T[] result = new T[length];
    Array.Copy(array, offset, result, 0, length);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: LINQ isn't the best solution for everything, but it can still make for a more readable solution in this case.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Agreed (see also my other answer to this question). But if readability is the problem, there's nothing that a few extension methods couldn't fix. :-)